# Exchange 2016 Std after upgraded .Net 4.7.2 Cannot login Exchange Admin Center

Tags: exchange-2016

Does anyone who experienced after upgraded the .net 4.7.2, I can see the Exchange Admin Center login and once I type in the login name and password the browser only looping ?

Many thanks,
Dominic Ho

Comment: What is the CU?

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart the MSExchangeECPAppPool in IIS manager.
2. In IIS manager -> right-click Default Web Site -> Edit Bindings, check if the correct certificate is binding to 127.0.0.1 and All Unassigned for port 443.
3. If issue remains, we could reset the ECP VD then run IISReset.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/284d556f-7554-493b-9f86-ed9eabd639a8/ecp-login-loop?forum=exchangesvradmin